# Excel VBA fails to call a COM method (built with .NET) that uses multithreading

Tags: .net, multithreading, vba, excel, com-interop

This C# code is in a .NET 4.5 `ComVisible` assembly:

## C# Code

```c#
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("22341223-9264-12AB-C1B4-B4F112014C31")]
public interface IComWithTask
{
    void LongExecutionMethod(double x);
    void LongExecutionMethodAsync(double x);
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("23844123-9274-12CB-C1F4-B4F1521E4F33")]
public interface IComWithTaskEvents
{
    void OnLongExecutionMethodComplete(double x);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IComWithTaskEvents))]
[Guid("E4F27AA4-1932-2196-1234-121CF2722C42")]
[ProgId("ComWithTask")]
public class ComWithTask : IComWithTask
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void LongExecutionMethodComplete(double x);
    public event LongExecutionMethodComplete OnLongExecutionMethodComplete;

    public void LongExecutionMethod(double x)
    {
        if (OnLongExecutionMethodComplete != null)
        {
            OnLongExecutionMethodComplete(x * x);
        }
    }

    public void LongExecutionMethodAsync(double x)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
        {
            var onLongExecutionMethodComplete = OnLongExecutionMethodComplete;
            if (onLongExecutionMethodComplete != null)
            {
                onLongExecutionMethodComplete(x * x);
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

From Excel 2010 32bit VBA, I've got the following behavior:

## VBA Code

```vba
Private WithEvents oComWithTask As ComWithTask

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set oComWithTask = New ComWithTask
End Sub

Public Sub LongExecutionMethod()
    ' Works as expected
    Call oComWithTask.LongExecutionMethod(2)
End Sub

Public Sub LongExecutionMethodAsync()
    ' Does NOT work!
    Call oComWithTask.LongExecutionMethodAsync(3)
End Sub

Private Sub oComWithTask_OnLongExecutionMethodComplete(ByVal x As Double)
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

I am aware that I am spinning a thread inside .NET when calling `LongExecutionMethodAsync`, and I am aware that office applications are single threaded.

I did find a great literature on calling COM components from .NET in a multithreaded way, but couldn't find any resource that goes the other way around, i.e. VBA calling a multithreaded .NET wrapped with COM method.

> Any thoughts on how to make `LongExecutionMethodAsync` work with
>   multithreading and could you point me to any related resource on this
>   subject? 
>   Also, do you have other suggestions for triggering async events in VBA?

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker.  Fire the event in a RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: You probably don't have a synchronization provider.  Check the value of System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.  If it is null then the event handler will run on the wrong thread.  Same issue with TPL.  You could create a hidden Winforms Form object in your initialization code to get a provider.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have updated the code above to reflect my implementation of the `BackgroundWorker`. The `SynchronizationContext` is null, but I am not in a Winform environment, it would be fishy to add the WinForm libraries for this. This is a COM/.NET library that will add some functions to Excel but has no GUI.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't want to do what you need to do to make this work.  SynchronizationContext.Current must not be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is working as expected, the problem was the life span of the object in VBA which was dying before the raise of the event.